# Printing from loop within a function: different output

Tags: python

I am writing a function which iterates through a list and processes each job, I'd like to check I've written it correctly, so I've added `print(body)` to my function after the processing code, which I expected to show me each line with different content as per the job list, but I am seeing all rows with the same result.

Here is my function:

```
# Iterate through the requests and execute them

def update_conversions(service):

  for req in request_bodies:
    request = service.conversion().update(body=req)

    print(body)
```

And the output is the content of the last item in the list, 10 times. The list is 10 items long.

When I iterate through the list and simply print out the contents, I see all 10 items with different content as expected:

```
def printer():   
    for req in request_bodies:
    print(req)
```

What is the difference between these two requests that is causing the first to repeat the last row multiple times?

Comment: Your first example isn't reproducible because `request_bodies` and `body` are not defined. Also, you can't tell what's going on there without knowing what `service.conversion().update(body=req)` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the level of the variable `body`, I hadn't noticed that it was within the `request` variable.

Changing my code to `print(request.body)` shows the expected result, one row for each item in the list.